# Spring Boot authentication results in recursion and StackOverflowError using an AuthenticationManager

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

Why does the use of an AuthenticationManager results in a StackOverflowError? Somewhere in the authentication process there seems to be a recursive call, but unfortunately I have no idea how to counter this.

Here the code:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);

    authManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("{noop}password").roles("USER");

    return authManagerBuilder.build();
}
```

The login with correct data works, but as soon as username or password are not correct one of the following problems occurs:
With wrong username an infinite loop:

```
...
o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to find user 'admin'
o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to find user 'admin'
o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to find user 'admin'
o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
...
```

With correct username but wrong password a recursion resulting in a StackOverflowError:

```
...
o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to authenticate since password does not match stored value
o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to authenticate since password does not match stored value
o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to authenticate since password does not match stored value
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline.forEachWithCancel(IntPipeline.java:161) ~[na:na]
...
```

There are no other Beans set except the SecurityFilterChain and the PasswordEncoder. So I wonder why the conventional use of an InMemoryUserDetailsManager Bean works, but the use of the same functionality with the help of an AuthenticationManager leads to problems?

---

edit:
Because requested, here the complete code sample:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authManager) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
                        .mvcMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .mvcMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('USER')"))

                .formLogin(FormLoginConfigurer::permitAll)
                .authenticationManager(authManager)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder =
                http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);

        authManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                .password("{noop}password")
                .roles("USER");

        return authManagerBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and overriding `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)`? You might be short-circuiting other default configuration by building the shared builder, which can only be built once.

Comment: Yes, but this didn't help. FYI, the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated, instead you use a SecurityFilterChain Bean.

Comment: Please show us the rest of our code, we need the full picture.

Comment: @Toerktumlare: thanks for your interest. I've added the compelte sample to my request.

Comment: If you enable debug logging (which you should do before asking here) im guessing you are getting redirected to /error which then wont allow you access since you have not whitelisted it, which will redirect yo to /error again etc etc

Comment: Yes I have enabled debug logging, I've set it even to TRACE. And as I've written in my question, all I get is either an infinite loop error `o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to find user 'admin'` or an StackOverflowError `o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to authenticate since password does not match stored value`.

Comment: And additionally fyi, I've simplyfied the example, but even with correct error handling the result is the same. Btw: if there were a redirecting problem with an unauthorized /error path, this would be shown in the log. I've posted the log, and there is no /error error, there is a recursion caused by whatever, but not by that.

Answer (score 0):

Since Spring 5.4, it is recommended to move towards a component-based security configuration. Actually, `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` has been deprecated in Spring Security 5.7.0-M2.

For the kind of authentication you seem to need in this example, I'd say you could use this, as presented in the official docs:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

This article explains other scenarios as well, like creating a custom
`AuthenticationManager`: https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter#ldap-authentication

Comment: As I've mentioned, the conventional use of an InMemoryUserDetailsManager Bean works - but his is not what I am asking for. I want to understand how to use an AuthenticationManager for InMemoryAuthentication, not to use this in production, but to get a deeper grasp of how Spring Boot works. I want to get this done, and then I can decide, which way to go for. The sunny side best practice solutions won't help me to gain a deeper understanding...